# Alone in the corner - who am I?

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle

I'm always alone in the corner of the (usually) black/white surface,

Although sometimes people come to me at the time of exit,

You have to cross 14 bridges for a vacation from me,

I'm half of my real name,

And another half known as animal.

not a fixed size figure,

You don't find me twice.

Comment: tag computer???

Comment: Could you explain the ```not a fixed size figure, ```?

Comment: I think you got your answer @A.D... :)

Comment: @leoll2 I changed it to computer-puzzle, which already has a tag wiki and a meta discussion supporting its existence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It's the escape key on a keyboard

I'm always alone in the corner of the (usually) black/white surface,

> on a top left corner of a keyboard, usually keyboards are black and white

Although sometimes people come to me at the time of exit,

> escape means also exit

You have to cross 14 bridges for a vacation from me,

> there is 14 keys between escape key and pause key (F1 to F12, prtscrn and scroll lock)

I'm half of my real name,

> only half of escape is written on the key

And another half known as animal.

> the other half is ape, which is an animal

not a fixed size figure,

> I can't think of something for that one

You don't find me twice.

> there is only one escape key on a keyboard

Comment: Answer for "not a fixed size figure:" not all escape keys have the same shape.

Comment: Maybe the *not a fixed size figure* relates to the key having a different physical shape and size on different keyboards?

Comment: I thought of that but it applies to a lot of keys on a keyboard.

Comment: The same goes for some of the other properties ( for example : you don't find me twice ). If the answer is an element of a particular set it narrows the answer down, even if there are more elements in that set.

Comment: @QBziZ Sure, but it could have also an other meaning. It could be a word play like the *14 bridges*.

Comment: @A.D.  I considered the wordplay to be the word 'figure' not meant as a number but as a synonym for the word 'shape'.

Comment: @QBziZ OK, I think I understand what you meant

Comment: well done @A.D. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is the

> Escape Key. I think that the first line gave it away, because of the awkwardness of the "black/white" part. The Escape key is also only labelled as "esc", and the rest of the word that is not shown is "ape", which is an animal.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.se  Just to let you know, providing a duplicate answer has little value unless it has a better explanation than the previous answer.  Duplicate answers are likely to be downvoted and eventually deleted.